# Must I set root document in 2 places? Mamp/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mamp

I have an issue of having to set my root doc in both the vhost file and in the MAMP preferences. If I only set in the vhost file and leave the root in MAMP preferences pointed at the htdocs folder under the MAMP dir, I cannot get past my main page in my laravel app. The main page loads fine but once I hit any buttons that route, I get an error stating 'The requested URL /task was not found on this server.'.  Please advise on what I am missing here.

Comment: It sounds like a `mod_rewrite` issue. Is the .htaccess file setup correctly for laravel?

Comment: I installed my laravel project with composer. Should I have to change something in my .htaccess file?

Comment: Not necessarily. Check `mod_rewrite` is enabled in `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf`, and check that `AllowOverride` is `All` - otherwise Apache will ignore your .htaccess file that contains your rewrite rules. If you need to change either make sure you restart MAMP.

Comment: I see 'AllowOverride None' like 10 different times throughout the http.conf file. One of the times says 'All', the rest say ''None'. Should they all be set to 'All'?

Comment: Hard to say but assuming your default configuration it's the one within `<Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs">`

Comment: LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so  <-- will this satisfy the mod_rewrite you spoke of? Thats the only place i see it mentioned in the httpd.conf file.

Comment: Moreover, I can use php artisan serve and everything works fine. :(